# php password_hash() non used characters

Tags: php, php-password-hash

Is there a list of characters not used to generate the hash in PHP's password_hash()? I'm looking for a quick/cheap way of indicating which proprietary algorythm or standard password_hash() was used to generate the hash and would like to just tag on a single character to the front of the string returned but can't seem to find a list of characters the function doesn't use in the return value.

Comment: Not sure why you want to do this?

Comment: several algorythms used across a few applications and i need a way to quickly and easily identify the string as to which algorythm was used. not all use the password_hash yet. checking the first char of the string is the prefered way they want

Comment: This sounds like an awfully bad idea. I also don't think there are 'unused' characters.

Comment: I agree but what they want (smh), was hoping to find a source to verify the no unused characters thing.

Comment: Well there is [password_get_info()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-get-info.php). You can feed it a hash and get information about it. You will have to check what it returns when you give it a non-password_hash() hash. There is a pattern in the hashes PHP generates, have you spotted that? For instance, mine all start with `$2x$20$`, I think that's the information you can see with the function I mentioned.

Comment: it's the proprietary hashes causing the problem, they don't use the standard format like that. can't get an answer if any of those start with a $ which would make it quick.

Comment: let's review; you want to assign and add a character to the password hash depending on which characters do not contain it. summarizing your idea so you would identify what type of hash / algorithm was used for the password? If you want to do this, I assure you that the idea of how to identify the algorithm used in the hash string is wrong ... since the idea of the hash is to completely hide any trace of how a password was generated and that is completely irreversible. In another term, encryption is the one that does or can have this viability, and a hash is not the same as an encryption.

Comment: @walternuñez A hash function performs an irreversible one way function on some input, there is no risk to security to store how the password was hashed, to obscure it would be an act of security through obscurity, in reality, providing no additional protection. In fact, this is very common to do for systems that support multiple hashing algorithms, even the Linux [`crypt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) function does it and is used for `/etc/shadow`

Comment: @walternuñez looking for a non-clashable set of characters to identify if i should push the password through the standard password_verify or one of the non-standard algorythms. Sorry, not looking to rewrite or do anything to the hash itself just which verify algorythm to push the password thru.

Comment: doing of checks: there are many characters that the password_hash () does not use in the return string: "*", "-", "¡", "!" This can help you identify the Algorithm used; but I do not know how effective it is, unfortunately you should do any verification at the moment it is generated; if you have Many users; You should ask him to change his password for security since a new system that requires it is implemented.

Comment: Is there a list of these characters?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation for `password_hash`:

> The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash.
>   Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is
>   included in it. This allows the password_verify() function to verify
>   the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm
>   information.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

You can use `password_get_info` to obtain this information from a hash:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-get-info.php

If the provided value is an unsupported/unknown hash this function will return:

```
Array ( 
    [algo] => 0 
    [algoName] => unknown 
    [options] => Array ( ) 
)
```

Comment: thank you, sorry yes i had already tried that solution...this would have worked if there was only 1 proprietary algorythm. Unknown does not help identify which non standard hash algorythm was used. So a char switch to know if i should push it through the password_verify() or one of the other algorythms. Moving towards standardization but it's a slow process and looking for a quick approvable fix in the meantime.

Comment: Why not just use `password_get_info` to identify if it's a non standard hash and if it is `unknown` then pass it to your legacy verify code?

Comment: There is more than 1 legacy algorythm :(